# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, appium, ui-testing

I am trying to automate my hybrid app, where I need to enter details in an input field but using `send_keys("Text value")` is not working in my case. I am getting the exception 
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'`

```
    def test_login(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    loginemail = self.driver.find_element_by_id("userId")
    loginpass = self.driver.find_element_by_id("userPassword")
    email = loginemail.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='userId']/input")
    email.click()

    email.send_keys("xxxxlabs.com")
```

Here is the full error message:

```
File "/home/martial/PycharmProjects/pytestAndroid/test_login_android.py", line 45, in test_login
email.send_keys("xxxxlabs.com")
File "/home/martial/PycharmProjects/pytestAndroid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
File "/home/martial/PycharmProjects/pytestAndroid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 491, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/home/martial/PycharmProjects/pytestAndroid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/martial/PycharmProjects/pytestAndroid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
raise wde
File "/home/martial/PycharmProjects/pytestAndroid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 24, in check_response
super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)
File "/home/martial/PycharmProjects/pytestAndroid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error when using chromedriver **v2.33** - when I updated to **v2.36** the error went away (this was on the mac using the chromedriver_mac64.zip file downloaded from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: org.openqa.selenium.webdriverexception: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'. Please look into below steps to resolve such error.

**Answer**: **Update browser version**. Please follow below steps to get the latest version of browsers.

1. Go to: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. CTRL+F and search "Third Party Browser Drivers". All browsers are listed there.
3. Click on browser name/version -It redirects to the another page. (E.g.- http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.36/)
4. Download appropriate driver for your operating system.
5. Place driver into one of folder from where you are calling that driver to your selenium webdriver scripts. It works without any error.

Thanks :) !!